# Finding matrix given eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

a) Let $B$ be a 2x2 symmetric matrix and let $u$, $v$  be two eigenvectors of $B$ associated with the eigenvalues $w$ and $l$ respectively. Suppose $u$ = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1/\sqrt2\\
  -1/\sqrt2
\end{array}
\right] $$
and $v$ = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1/\sqrt2\\
  1/\sqrt2
\end{array}
\right] $$
with $w$= 1 and $l$=3 respectively, find matrix $B$.

b) Let $C$ be another symmetric matrix of order n with a characteristic polynomial $(w-w_1)(w-w_2)...(w-w_n)$ where $w_1≤w_2≤...≤w_n$. Prove that for any nonzero vector $x$ that belongs in $R^n$, $w_1≤x^TCx/x^Tx≤w_n$.

What I have done:
For part (a), converting $u$ and $v$ to orthogonal basis, I get $u_o$=$$ \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1\\
  -1
\end{array}
\right] $$ and $v_o$=$$ \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1\\
  1
\end{array}
\right] $$. Letting $M$ = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  1&0\\
  0&3
\end{array}
\right] $$ and $S$ = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  1&1\\
  -1&1
\end{array}
\right] $$, the matrix B is obtained by putting together $SMS^{-1}$ = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  2&1\\
  1&2
\end{array}
\right] $$.

However, for part (b), while I can derive that $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$ are eigenvalues of C, I am unsure of how to proceed, hence may I get some help for this?

Comment: Use $Av=\lambda v$ to get system of linear equations and solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\lVert x\rVert=1$. Then $x^Tx=1$. On the other hand, let $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ an orthonormal basis of eigenvecors, such that the eigenvalu corresponding to $v_k$ is $w_k$. Then $x$ can be written as $\alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_kv_k$. So, $Cx=\alpha_1w_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_nw_nv_n$ and so$$x^TCX=\lvert\alpha_1\rvert^2w_1+\cdots+\lvert\alpha_n\rvert^2w_n.$$Since $\lvert\alpha_1\rvert^2+\cdots+\lvert\alpha_n\rvert^2=1$, this number is between $w_1$ and $w_n$.

If $x$ is an arbitrary non-zero vector, you can apply the previus result to $\frac x{\lVert x\rVert}$.

Comment: Sir Why in particular is $\lvert\alpha_1\rvert^2+\cdots+\lvert\alpha_n\rvert^2=1$?

Comment: Because the basis is orthonormal and $\lVert x\rVert=1$.

Comment: Oh ok sir. got it !